# Android Compose UI testing: how get the Text from a node

Tags: android, testing, android-jetpack-compose

I want in my test get the Text from a node.

```
       **var nodes=onAllNodes(myNode).fetchSemanticsNodes()**

       println("Test_printlog ########### start ${nodes.size}")
       // give a corret number 
       for (node in nodes) {
            println("TestNODE ${node.config}")
```

I have:

```
TestNODE SemanticsConfiguration@972964b{ mergeDescendants=true,TestTag : myTestTag, Text : my text,
```

If I want to get the Text property I tried to use `node.config.get`
but wat is the parameter to pass to the get to get the text?

in the documentation said:

> androidx.compose.ui.semantics.SemanticsConfiguration public final
> operator fun  get(
> key: SemanticsPropertyKey ): T Retrieves the value for the given property if one has been set. If a value has not been set,
> throws IllegalStateException

I try several time... but I have always error

like for example if I use node.config.get("Text")

> Type mismatch. Required: SemanticsPropertyKey<TypeVariable(T)> Found:
> String

What is the correct syntax to get the Text property from `node.config.get`?

Comment: Why not useonNodeWithTag?

Comment: Vahid Garousi, I have to verify that a text contains a substring in several nodes, not in one, so I need to get the text property for each node.

Comment: can you update you post? add your test function by doing that i can test it in my system and try to fix that

Answer (score 1):

I found.....
add:

```
import androidx.compose.ui.semantics.SemanticsProperties.Text
```

and use

```
node.config.getOrNull(Text)}
```

in this way you can also find all the other semantic properties:

```
import androidx.compose.ui.semantics.SemanticsProperties.TestTag
 node.config.getOrNull(TestTag)}
```